# Deleting files in sub-directories, excluding root directory

Tags: powershell

I have written a Powershell script that is supposed to delete files in sub-directories that are older than 25 days.

```
#
# Variables.
#
$days = 25
$src = "C:\Users\ArifSohM\Desktop\TestFolder\"

# Check if files are older than 25 days.

Get-childitem -path $src |
ForEach-Object {
    $age = New-Timespan ($_.LastWriteTime) $(get-date)

    if($age.days -gt $days) {
    Remove-Item $_.FullName -force
    Write-host "$_ is older than 25 days and has been deleted." -ForegroundColor yellow
    }
}
#
```

This  works partially fine, but when I run this command it also deletes files in the root directory. This is my folder structure:

- Test Folder (Root)

  - Directory1 (Folder)

    - File1
    - File2
  - Directory2 (Folder)

    - File1
    - File2
  - File1
  - File2

So, I want to delete everything in `Directory1` & `Directory2`, but not in `Test Folder`. Can this be done?

Comment: Should the word “, as”, be “ except that,”? i.e. “This works partially fine expect that, when…”

Comment: Probably, but you get my point I hope. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done (among other ways) by using `Get-ChildItem -Directory` to select only directories, and the cycling through them.

Note that your/my function will not handle sub-folders inside sub-folders. This is just a simple adjustment of your original script.

```
$days = 25
$src = "C:\Users\ArifSohM\Desktop\TestFolder\"

# Check if files are older than 25 days.

$dirs = Get-childitem -path $src* -Directory 

foreach ($dir in $dirs) {
    Get-childitem -path $dir | ForEach-Object {
        $age = New-Timespan ($_.LastWriteTime) $(get-date)

        if($age.days -gt $days) {
        Remove-Item $_.FullName -force
        Write-host "$_ is older than 25 days and has been deleted." -ForegroundColor yellow
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. I ran your modified script and I got the following error: 
"Get-childitem : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\ArifSohM\Directory1' because it does not exist." - It thinks that the folders within the root directory don't exist.

Comment: I've sorted it, where it says "$dirs = Get-childitem -path $src -Directory " I amended it so it reads "$dirs = Get-childitem -path $src\* -Directory